# how to get empty row in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this citys in my database:

```
city1
city2
city3
city4
```

i what to see this in my DropDownList:

```
[empty]
city1
city2
city3
city4
```

this is my bind code:

```
SQL = "select distinct City from MyTbl order by City";
dsClass = new DataSet();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsClass, "MyTbl");
adp.Dispose();
DropDownList3.DataSource = dsClass.Tables[0];
DropDownList3.DataTextField = dsClass.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
DropDownList3.DataValueField = dsClass.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

how to do it (asp.net C#) ?

thanks in  advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Binding DropDownList through below mentioned code you can add new item in DropDownList

```
DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
```

You can replace `String.Empty` to your desire value.

Comment: Do this just after you've bound the dropdownlist to the data.

Comment: @5arx: You are right. I have forget to mentioned in my answer. thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, String.Empty);
```

which is the same as

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
```

or

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty));
```

or

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem());
```

Comment: I think in third line of your code you have forget to close Insert tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID='DropDownList1' runat='server' DataSourceID='ObjectDataSource1'
        DataTextField='ProductName' DataValueField='ProductID' AppendDataBoundItems='true'
        >
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Enabled="true" Selected="True" Value='-1'>
            </asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

by setting AppendDataBoundItems = true in the DropDownList markup, DropDownList would append the items from datasource after the asp:ListItem (specified in the markup).

This could be achieved from code-behind but this is lot simpler.